# Existing package for aruco-based localization

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm looking for an existing package that will let me recover the position of a moving camera from identifying static aruco boards in the scene. The package `ar-sys` (http://wiki.ros.org/ar_sys) seems to do exactly what I want, except that the git repo seems to no longer exist. The indigo builds are available through `apt` but conflict with `ros-indigo-aruco`. Can anyone either
(1) help figure out what happened to the package, and update the ROS package index accordingly
(2) suggest an alternate package?
I'd prefer not to build yet another package for the same task, but can if necessary. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292984/existing-package-for-aruco-based-localization/) by [raronson](https://answers.ros.org/users/35618/raronson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently used [aruco_detect](http://wiki.ros.org/aruco_detect) successfully. It worked well first time using the `DICT_5X5_50` dictionary. (I only needed a few landmarks.) The only problem I had was that it needed to run on a Raspberry Pi. `aruco_detect` (or the underlying library in OpenCV) could only process about 1fps on the RPi. I used the `message_filters` package to drop image frame rate down to 1fps before using the detector. (If the frame rate is too fast for `aruco_detect`, the node eventually used enough memory – presumably for message buffering – to hang the RPi.)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0